# Adding hyperlink dynamically to images using jquery cycle plugin for transitions

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I am working on a slideshow using the jquery [cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int.html) for transitions.
Now all works fine till I add a hyperlink to the image.I am trying to add a hyperlink if a user wishes to add so i have a set button for each image in my console.If a user selects a hyperlink and clicks set,it should be set.Now the hyperlink is set correctly,but,then the transitions are applied to the **anchor** tags instead of the **img** tags.
When I set the link the img tag is wrapped inside the anchor tag like this.

```
     <a href="www.google.com" id="link" class="link"> 
        <img id="imgBoxRot_1_1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 3; opacity: 0;" src="http://localhost/images/layout/slideShow/gallImg1.jpg">
     </a>
```

I create this anchor tag dynamically like this,and append it to the image.

```
    var newA = document.createElement("a");
    newA.setAttribute("id","lnkImgRotImg_"+iCount+"_"+idT);
    newA.setAttribute("href",document.getElementById(lnk).value);
    newA.setAttribute("class","aTransLink");
    newA.setAttribute("target","_blank");
```

Before setting the anchor tag the plugin works fine and transitions are applied,but after adding a anchor to image,the transitions are applied to the anchor tag instead of the image.How can I fix this?
Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After studying the plugin documentation I learned that,the plugin is default applied to the **first tag** that is inside the div to which it is applied.
That is,if we have

```
<div class="">
     <img></img>
     <img></img>         
</div>
```

Now,if I wrap an anchor around the image like this,

```
<div class="">
     <a href="">
       <img></img>
     </a>

     <img></img>         
</div>
```

The plugin gets confused between an image tag and an anchor tag and applies the transitions to the **anchor instead of the image tag**(as it is the first after the div to which the cycle plugin is applied). Therefore,I wrapped all the images initially inside an anchor tag each(**Earlier I added anchors dynamically**) and applied the plugin on the anchors itself instead of image tag.